# angular2gridster add remove button (x) on right hand corner

Tags: angular, gridster

I want the widget on the grid to have remove button on top right hand corner.  Is there a option that need to be set to enable it.  If not how to display the remove button (x) on the right hand corner?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware off. You can however add a css { position: relative } to a container inside the gridster-item, and then a position absolute to the button.

```
<gridster-item *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div style="position:relative">
   <button style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0"
 (click)="myRemoveFunction(item)">X</button>
   ...
  </div>
</gridster-item>
```